# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-questions

I only have a [link to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034137/) from [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034812/idiom-vs-pattern).  I have 10k rep on SO, so can see [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/).

Where has 2034137 gone, and why was it deleted using some uncommon method?  (Or why can't I see it if it was deleted normally?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was merged with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276173/what-are-your-favorite-c-coding-style-idioms). Merging, unfortunately, completely removes the question being merged *from*.

Comment: Thanks.  How did you find that out, or is your memory just *that good*?

Comment: @Gnome: oddly enough, I *did* remember the question... But no, I don't memorize IDs; Google's cache FTW! (for future reference, if you can dig up the ID of an *answer* to a merged question, it'll take you to the same answer in its new location)

Comment: excellent tip on the answer IDs.. never thought of that

Comment: @Jeff: I realize it's fairly rare, but you might want to consider altering the processing of permalinks for answers to fall back on the logic for resolving the URL for an answer ID when the question ID isn't found...

Answer (score 0):

Deleted questions can still be voted to undelete, but IIRC they are also purged after a period of inactivity.